# Return functions recursively to form nested functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm trying to build a function in JS that has a return composed of different nested functions based on a parameter passed by the user.

```
function addA(otherFunction)
{
//gets the result from some base function and modifies it
//e.g. +1
}

function addB(otherFunction)
{
//does the same thing as addA, except different values. Consider it a variation of addA.
//eg. -1
}

function constr(input)
{
//based on the chars in input, we will recursively select a new function to be applied.
//the value of this function should be a function
if (...) return addA(constr(shorterInput))
if (*last char) return addA
if (*last char) return addB
if (...) return addB(constr(shorterInput))
}
```

So far, my script is recognizing addA and and addB as functions. But when it strings two functions together, for example

```
addB(addA)
```

The type becomes undefined. Can anybody let me know why it does not register as a function and/or the proper way to return nested functions. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is the real code:

```js
function cons(a,b)
{
  return function (selector) {
    return selector(a,b);
  };
}

function a(list)
{
  function aHelper(a,b)
  {
    return a
  }
  return list(aHelper);
}

function d(list)
{
  function dHelper(a,b)
  {
    return b
  }
  return list(dHelper);
}

function abc(input)
{
  if (input.length==0 || input==null) return null;
  var x=input.charAt(input.length-1);
  if (x==='a') 
  {
    if (input.length>1) 
    {
      var z=a(abc(input.substr(0,input.length-1)));
      return z;
    }
      return a;
  }
  if (x==='d')
  {
    if (input.length>1) 
    {
      var z=d(abc(input.substr(0,input.length-1)));
      return z;
    }
    return d;
  }
}
function show(list) {
  var sval;
  if (list == null) return '()';
  else if (typeof list!='string')
  {
    sval = '(' + show(a(list)) + ' ' + show(d(list)) + ')';
  }
  else 
  {
    sval=list;
  }
  return sval;
}

var func=abc('ad');
var func2=abc('a');
var list=cons('a',cons('b','c'));
console.log(typeof func);
console.log(typeof func2);
console.log(typeof list);
console.log(typeof func2(list));
console.log(typeof func(list));
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could post the real code you actually have problems with, not only some pseudo code.

Comment: The `otherFunction` parameter seems to be supposed to contain a function that can be called with a value and returns a value, right? The `addA` function you are passing is no such function, it is one that takes and returns other functions.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not being very clear, but my updated code should show that it isn't actually modifying a value, rather selecting one. In this case, it can either pick a string value, or another list (which is badly named, but is actually a function).

Comment: Thanks for the code. Where did you get this list representation from? It's horrible.

Comment: I can see where your problem lies, but I can't tell you how to solve it as I am unsure what you want `abc` to do. What is the task you're trying to accomplish? And what type do you think should `abc` have?

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately it's immutable. It's part of an assignment. Usually I'd refrain from directly seeking help with this kind of stuff, but I've exhausted my resources and I genuinely don't understand how to pass a nested function as a return.

Comment: @Bergi abc is supposed to have type "function", so that I can use `var newFunction=abc('adad');` As to what I'm trying to accomplish, you'll see the weird list constructor near the bottom. I basically need to generate a function that can locate a specific element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using `var list=cons('a',cons('b', cons('c', null)));`, right?

Comment: Btw, what do `a` and `d` stand for? Usually they're called [`head` and `tail` or `car` and `cdr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR#Other_computer_languages).

Comment: @Bergi yes and yes. The null doesn't really change anything but syntactically I should have included it. a and d are supposed to be car and cdr, my bad.

Comment: The `null` is important for detecting the end of a list. `cdr` should always return the rest of the list (a function) or null, not anything else.

Comment: Ahh yes! I understand now. But with an order of car(cdr) it's still not working. In fact, I've isolated the problem to the fact that car(cdr) is not a function. How else would you pass a nested function then? Thanks for much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `abc` is supposed to return a function that can process lists, like `a` or `d`. However, you match that signature only in 2 out of 7 cases:

- `return a`, `return d` are fine
- `return null` - that's not a callable value
- `z = d(…); return z` does return a list
- `z = a(…); return a` does return an element of the list (of whatever type)
- `d(abc(…))` and `a(abc(…))` use `abc` as if it would return a list

A correct implementation would look like this:

```
function abc(directions) {
    if (directions.length == 0) {
       return function id(list) { return list; }; // a function that does nothing
    }
    var f = directions[0] == 'a' ? car : cdr; // ignoring other values, you might also throw an error
    var processRest = abc(input.slice(1));

    return function(list) { // make a function to process a list
        var z = f(list); // do the current operation
        return processRest(z); // do the rest of operations
    };
}
```

Or even better/shorter with the help of higher-order function composition:

```
function id(x) { return x; }
function compose(f, g) {
    if (f == id) return g;
    if (g == id) return f;
    return function(x) { return f(g(x)); };
}
function abc(dirs) {
    return !dirs.length ? id : compose(abc(dirs.slice(1)), dirs[0]=='a'?car:cdr);
}
```

Comment: Try to fix it with these hints. I'm going to uncomment my solution if you've got something

Comment: The problem I have is that even if replace `z=d(abc)...` with `return a(d)`, it still considers `a(d)` as undefined`

Comment: You have to pass a list to `a`. Not a function like `d` or `abc(…)`

Comment: So would it be impossible then to use `abc` to construct a new function that implements `d` and then `a`? In the context of the `abc` function, there are no lists, since the functions don't have any inputs other than other functions.

Comment: No, it's not impossible. Right, in the context that `abc` operates in, there are only functions (like `a`, `d`, or the result of the recursive call). But inside these functions, there is a list, and you need to use that. Did you learn about closures yet? Use one.

Comment: I don't think I can let `abc` directly `car` or `cdr` an external list defined by `cons` since abc will later be assigned to a variable, say `func`.

Comment: @YinanWang Yes, that's what my answer states: `abc` needs to return a function (that then does the work). Have you used closures before?

Comment: I understand how it works but the f(list) is undefined for me?